# Did Karl Marx ever advocate anything?

Tags: history, marxism

[Marx](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karl_Marx) never advocated anything it seems. He never actually said communism was desirable, only that it would happen. The closest thing to advocating something would be the Gotha programme, but even then that's just a vague list of generic demands and not a specific law that he supported or opposed. It seems he spent most of his career getting involved in internal politics in the first international. Which, by the way, never got involved in legislature or lawmaking.

From Mark's article it does seem like he supported the franco Prussian war

> When the Franco-German War broke out in 1870, Marx and Engels disagreed with followers in Germany who refused to vote in the Reichstag in favour of the war

He also argued against [environmentalism/malthusianism](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/1081602X.2019.1702889?journalCode=rhof20), although that still isnt a law. He might [also have been critical of immigration](http://classicalmarxismvsimmigration.blogspot.com/?m=1). His slavery position was... [odd](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/full/10.1080/13569317.2019.1548094)

> In a 14 June 1853 letter to Engels, Marx indicated that, in the past, Jamaica had been importing new negro slaves all the time, making for a population mostly consisting of ‘newly imported barbarians’. On the contrary, the ‘present negro generation in America [represents] an indigenous product, more or less turned into Yankees, English speaking etc. and therefore becomes capable of emancipation’.85

From "The Civil War in the United States"

> in the Northern States, where Negro slavery is in practice unworkable, the white working class would gradually be forced down to the level of helotry in the event of a Southern victory

He wasn't even that much against slavery, he only stated a position one time in a letter signed by 50 other  people. [Example](http://socialdemocracy21stcentury.blogspot.com/2015/04/marx-on-slavery-in-his-1846-letter-to.html?m=1)

> Freedom and slavery constitute an antagonism. There is no need for me to speak either of the good or of the bad aspects of freedom. As for slavery, there is no need for me to speak of its bad aspects. The only thing requiring explanation is the good side of slavery. I do not mean indirect slavery, the slavery of proletariat; I mean direct slavery, the slavery of the Blacks in Surinam, in Brazil, in the southern regions of North America.

Also, slavery was overwhelmingly unpopular in Europe, so if he opposed slavery it wouldnt be a very distinct opinion.

Was there any real, specific, non theoretical law or policy that Karl Marx had an opinion on?

Comment: Does it answer to your question? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Civil_War_in_France

Comment: This Wikipedia article contains some wrong information. The only time Marx mentioned "dictatorship of proletariat" is in his letter to Weidemeyer, https://www.google.com/search?newwindow=1&rlz=1C1GCEU_enUS887US887&sxsrf=ALeKk03tRiih_Mjixw4AD0v08fLxGgHSHw%3A1596151785895&ei=6VcjX8KDNuvn_QaqpaCoDg&q=Karl+Marx+letter+to+Weidemeier&oq=Karl+Marx+letter+to+Weidemeier&gs_lcp=CgZwc3ktYWIQA1CnwgFY9O4BYIyBAmgAcAB4AIABhgGIAeEHkgEDMS44mAEAoAEBqgEHZ3dzLXdpesABAQ&sclient=psy-ab&ved=0ahUKEwiCnNLhkPbqAhXrc98KHaoSCOUQ4dUDCAw&uact=5

which was published long after Marx's death.

Comment: His writing on the Paris commune is just as indecisive

Comment: This is also not quite true. Marx's idea was that the Paris commune failed precisely because the organizers did not fight decisively enough. That was later explained in detail by Lenin.

Comment: But that's not the same as supporting or opposing it

Comment: -1 The last quote is seriously misleading. Marx [wasn't arguing for the good aspects of slavery](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/39414/did-karl-marx-write-that-slavery-had-good-sides-and-abolishing-it-would-indirect/39416). He was attributing the opinion to Proudhon (the start of the paragraph - "Let me now give you an example of Mr Proudhon's dialectics" - is purposefully omitted). Apart from that, your question is mostly stating your opinion and seems to be about discrediting Marx, not about asking a question in good faith.

Comment: @q3d: References? Pro-white means he thought that economy based on slavery is ineffective whence bad for the whites. And what does Engels have to do with it? He was a different person. You can as well say that Engels was Antifa because he wrote Anti-Duehring and Duehring later became a fascist.

Comment: @JohnBalvin: Marx certainly supported the Paris commune. Just read his text about it. He was against some non-proletarian aspects of it.

Comment: Marx didn't believe in transforming the society by peaceful means - according to him the only way forward was a revolution, while creating political parties promoting universal suffrage and welfare was essentially accepting the existing liberal order. Hence his disagreement with Lassalle and the subsequent critique of Gotha, which essentially focused on modifying the social contract, rather than overthrowing the system. This is why he rarely took positions on the current affairs.

Comment: What about the Manifesto of the Communist Party? I assume you're aware of it.

Answer (score 7):

To pick just one intesting if minor example, Marx clearly supported the abolition of slavery. For example, he signed [a letter](https://www.marxists.org/archive/marx/iwma/documents/1864/lincoln-letter.htm)
praising Abraham Lincoln and declaring "the triumphant war cry of your re-election is Death to Slavery". You can find many articles online discussing Marx's writings regarding slavery and the US Civil War.

Comment: But that seems to be for pro-white reasons

Comment: Yes, pro-white. As most 19th century philosophers, Marx was a racist, https://pure.uva.nl/ws/files/44504342/Marx_and_Engels_s_theory_of_history_making_sense_of_the_race_factor.pdf

Comment: It wasn't even that consistent of a position, he only opposed slavery 1 time and he was writing on behalf of other people

Comment: @JohnBalvin He wrote [an entire collection of articles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Civil_War_in_the_United_States) about it. He also [argues against slavery](https://www.marxists.org/archive/dunayevskaya/works/1979/outline-capital/ch06.htm) and for black emancipation in Das Kapital. He never argued for slavery, so saying that it wasn't a consistent position doesn't seem correct.

Comment: Marx opposed slavery on multiple occasions, and Engels used a comparison of capitalism to a new form of slavery precisely as a rhetorical device against capitalism. He ridiculed Proudhon, writing that only with Proudhon's logical leaps could one come to the conclusion that slavery had some good components. It's also unclear what is meant by "pro-white" in the case of opposing slavery, @MarkSapir's paper does not back that interpretation up.

Comment: @tim: and what exactly did Marx say about slavery in Der Kapital?

Comment: @q3d: References? Pro-white means he thought that economy based on slavery is ineffective whence bad for the whites. And what does Engels have to do with it? He was a different person. You can as well say that Engels was Antifa because he wrote Anti-Duehring and Duehring later became a fascist.

Comment: @MarkSapir As for Marx's argument against Proudhon, see here: https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/a/39416 and his articles on the civil war mentioned by tim, who references at least one line as quoted by Dunayevskaya on Marx's position of slavery in Capital. I'm really not sure what this discussion is about; it seems, given Marx's other positions, that the onus would be on someone accusing him of pro-slavery sentiments (or anti-slavery only for 'pro-white' reasons) to prove it. Slavery was very much on its way out in Marx's time, and he didn't feel the need to concern himself with it much.

Answer (score 4):

Marx of course advocated communism and did everything in his power to justify it and bring it closer. For example his role in the [first International](https://www.britannica.com/biography/Karl-Marx/Role-in-the-First-International) was very significant, This article says, in particular,

> Although he was neither its founder nor its head, he soon became its leading spirit.

What is true, though, Marx never promoted what is called "communism" now. Even Lenin would be an "anti-Marx" in his view. He also hated liberals, trade unionists and so on. His main ideological enemy was [Lassalle](https://www.marxists.org/archive/marx/works/1875/gotha/), the founder of what is now known as "democratic socialism".

Comment: That article says he just got involved in internal politics of the organization and destroyed it